# Why is buffer received over USB is not aligned on transmitted buffer length?

Tags: usb, stm32

I stream some data from STM32H7 USB (VCP) -> to PC, and after stream is finished I just send "end\0". And on PC side I just look at the start of received data block and if there is "end\0", I just wind up PC program.

This is STM32H7 code:

```
#define DMA_BUFFER_SIZE   2048
#define SIZE 2048

unsigned short int buffer[DMA_BUFFER_SIZE] __attribute__((section(".fast_buffer")));

// "end\0"
buffer[0] = 0x6E65;
buffer[1] = 0x0064;
buffer[2] = 0x0;
CDC_Transmit_HS(buffer, SIZE*sizeof(unsigned short int));
GPIOH->ODR ^= (0x1 << 2);
while(((USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef*)(hUsbDeviceHS.pClassData))->TxState != 0);
```

PC side:

```
#define NUMBER_OF_DATA_UNITS 2048
unsigned short int lpBuffer[NUMBER_OF_DATA_UNITS] = {0};
unsigned long nNumberOfBytesToRead = NUMBER_OF_DATA_UNITS*2;
unsigned long lpNumberOfBytesRead;
for(;;) {

  QueryPerformanceCounter(&startCounter);  
  ReadFile(
    hSerial,
    lpBuffer,
    nNumberOfBytesToRead,
    &lpNumberOfBytesRead,
    NULL
    );

  if(!strcmp((char *)lpBuffer, "end")) {
    CloseHandle(FileHandle);
    // we are finished
    break;
  }
  else if(lpNumberOfBytesRead > 0) {
    //write received data to the disk
  }
}// for(;;)
```

Sometimes the last data buffer that I get starts not with my "end\0" string, but with other data and my "end\0" string is somewhere in the middle of the last buffer, so I can't finish my routine properly. Why is this happens?

I transfer 2048*2 bytes in one batch from STM32 and receive 2048*2 bytes on PC side.

Maybe someone could just kick me in the right direction about how properly do things like that?

Edit:

I think I can just scan each block, but this is looks like unnecessary thing, and the gist of the question will be the same. Why sometimes my received buffers is not aligned on 2048*2 bytes length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this on PC side:

```
if(!strcmp((char *)lpBuffer[lpNumberOfBytesRead - 3], "end")) {
.... 
}
```

and something like this on STM32 side:

```
char *endstring = "end";
CDC_Transmit_HS(endstring, strlen(endstring) + 1); // <-- I do not certain about how is this thing work so maybe just strlen
GPIOH->ODR ^= (0x1 << 2);
while(((USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef*)(hUsbDeviceHS.pClassData))->TxState != 0);
```

simple trick, you only send 4 bytes packet at the end of the stream, and only check the last 4 bytes on the receiving end (PC side) so there is no need for any type of counter or etc. just check last 4 bytes of each packet that you get from STM32 no difference what size of packet you get.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, a USB connection is just a stream of bytes. There is no guarantee that a buffer used at one end corresponds to a buffer used at the other end. Your data needs to be formatted to live within this restriction, with some unambiguous in-band protocol to indicate message boundaries.

Furthermore, you need to make sure you check the value of `lpNumberOfBytesRead` BEFORE you try to do anything with the data — including searching for boundary flags. It could be anything between 0 and `nNumberOfBytesToRead`.

Comment: It's the virtual serial port implementation (particularly on the windows/driver side) that is a stream, not the underlying USB.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: The APIs that the OP is using at both ends of the link do not expose the underlying implementation details. It is pointless to raise such issues in this context.

Comment: The problem is that the text of your answer is literally false and may confuse future readers, because it incorrectly attributes this to USB and not the windows serial API.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: "Fundamentally" is NOT a reference to the underlying implementation. It refers to the fundamental concept used in the APIs. My text is literally correct.

Comment: No.  A USB API exposes packets.  The serial API in use does not.  The issue is not USB as you falsely claim, but rather the serial stream.  If you said "a virtual serial over USB connection" you would be correct.  But instead you wrote something which is false.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: No. The buffers used in the API have *nothing whatsoever* to do with the actual packets transferred at the link level.